# How to change session suspend time in RStudio server

Tags: rstudio-server

RSutdio-server installation behaves as follows:

> 1. Whenever working as usual, leave the web client unattended for some time (not sure but maybe around 1-2 hours?)
> 2. After pause, click anything to get a notification "Resuming R session..."
> 3. /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rsession -u username grows back from ~120MB to proper size (usually not less than 11GB which is how I left it), but it takes 5 times slower than reading CSV in my desktop.
> 4. After success, RStudio usually gets responsive

How can I change the time after RStudio server sleeps ?

Also, I don't understand why it takes 3 times slower to read a big CSV on my university server as compared to my laptop. They have 24 Intel Xeon cores and 256GB RAM. I have i5 and 12GB RAM.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question "How to change session suspend time in RStudio server has a new answer" has been answered by official support board at [support.rstudio.com](http://support.rstudio.com)

It's possible to configure the session-timeout in RStudio Server if you have admin access by modifying the `session-timeout-minutes` value in `/etc/rstudio/rsession.conf`

See this article for more details:

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552316-Configuring-the-Server